# Facial traits recognition with tags

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

I am looking for a way for a program to recognize the type of traits of a face.

I would need for example the computer to be able to say that "This type of face is oval, this type of nose is Aquiline, those ears are flat etc..

The same way one can make a video-game character but in the other way around.
From the actual face to a series of tags.

Comment: What have you tried and/or researched so far?

Comment: I do not know where to start, it's a very complexe topic @Rethunk